# How can I do to customize the actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hi guys I wanna ask you if it is possible to completely redesign the actionbar. I have no buttons on my bar and I want to place a "png" file instead of the default bar..is it possible? Thank you so much :)

Comment: check my git repo: https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/CustomActionBar

Comment: It is possible **not to use any ActionBar at all**. Just place any control which has a drawable background settable (I normally use a TextView) on the top of your Activity and set its background image. A TextView may also contain a **title** and **one or more "icons"** (compound drawables). And it's also **clickable**, if needed.

Comment: @Funkystein this work but, I have a map below the TextView, so when the map appear the textview disappear :/

Comment: Design your layout properly, A RelativeLayout container (I prefer this one) may help: set the TextView as `alignParentTop="true"` and the map as `layout_below="@id/yourTextView_ID"` and `layout_height="match_parent"` (to fill the remaining space)

Comment: As the **overall** (root) container. It contains everything. As such, its chinldren can be **relatively** positioned.

Comment: @Funkystein ok it defenetly works :D awesome! really thank you ! ..another question. is it possible that my map goes under the png? With a screenshot of my app maybe all will be clear.. watch here -> http://i277.photobucket.com/albums/kk71/ErikaSparrow/14-15.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63541/discussion-between-pierpaolo-ercoli-and-funkystein).

Comment: Yes. Just skip the `layout_below` attribute to the map. And add `alignParentTop="true"` to it

Comment: I made an answer out of my comments, so that you can accept it and remove it from the Unanswered Questions Queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible not to use any ActionBar at all.
Just place any control which has a drawable background settable (I normally use a TextView) on the top of your Activity and set its background image.

A TextView may also contain a **title** and **one or more "icons"** (compound drawables).
And it's also **clickable**, if needed.

If you design your layout properly; a RelativeLayout container (I prefer this kind of container) may help: set the TextView as `alignParentTop="true"` and the map as `layout_below="@id/yourTextView_ID"` and `layout_height="match_parent"` (to fill the remaining space).

Let the RelativeLayout be the **overall** (root) container, so that it contains everything.
As such, its children can be positioned **relatively**.

To let the map be positioned **under** the "title", Just skip the layout_below attribute to the map.   And add `alignParentTop="true"` to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use action bar functionality like Up navigation or drawer navigation toogle from action bar.You can use at window like this and style your title in your theme:

```
getWindow.requestFeature(FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

And at style file like this:

```
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">@dimen/title_height</item>
<item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitle</item>
```

If you want to use action bar functionality, override action bar custom view by this:

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
```